# JMeter redirection URL

Tags: redirect, jmeter

I'm trying to stress test a website where people are able to create reports which are stored in SQL, etc...
Let's say the page orders are the followings:

- mywebsite.com/home
- mywebsite.com/reports
- mywebsite.com/reports/create
- mywebsite.com/reports/2

As you can see, there is a sub-page called reports. It has a create button. Then the user is being redirected to the create sub-page. When it clicks the save button, it get's redirected straight to its reports sub-page. Now my issue is I don't see the redirection URL that is being received by the browser where to be redirected. Maybe the report ID will be 3 or 4, or 123.... etc. I want this value as a variable. At the create sub-page I have a `Response code: 302` but I can't figure out where is it redirecting the user to and where can I modify this URL value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are being redirected the server sends [Location header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Location) which indicates where exactly you are being redirected

[image: JMeter Redirect]

In order to extract this redirect URL you can add [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) postprocessor as a child of the main request and configure it like:

- Apply to: `Main sample and sub-samples`
- Field to check: `Response headers`
- Reference Name: anything meaningful, i.e. `location`
- Regular Expression: `Location: (.*)`
- Template: `$1$`

Assuming everything goes well you should be able to refer the extracted value as `${location}` where required.

References:

- [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter)
- [JMeter: Regular Expressions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)

Comment: Thanks. This was what I was looking for. Unfortunately the location is again the `/create` sub-page. Which I can't understand why... But on the `/create` I can't find any redirections or anything. :/